# Cannot find RequireJs objects in the DOM (for UI Access)

Tags: javascript, dom, requirejs

I am trying to set up requireJs and am following the 'simple one page app' example from the requirejs [getting started](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) section.

The problem I have is that I cannot find the objects in the DOM to work with. If i pause/debug during load, I can run the methods in the console, but using 'window', I cannot find the objects in the DOM to call from the UI. The click event shown below will fail. What am I doing wrong please? Here's my code:

UI

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <p>test2</p>
      <button onclick="man.dogAlert()">Alert</button>
    </div>

</div>


<script data-main="../Scripts/testreq/main" src="../Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

App.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '~/Scripts/testreq',
    paths: {
      'jQuery': '~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2',
    },
    shim: {
      'jQuery': {
        exports: '$'
      }
    },
});

// Start loading the main app file. Put all of
// your application logic in there.
requirejs(['main']);
```

Main.js

```
define(function (require) {

    var man = require('man');

    return man;
});
```

Man.js

```
define(["dog"], function (dog) {

    console.log("man js loaded");

    var dogAlert = function () {
      alert(dog.getMyDogsNameReq());
    };

    var man = {
        dogAlert: dogAlert,
    }

    return man;
});
```

Dog.js

```
define(function () {

    var getMyDogsNameReq = function () {
        return 'fido';
    };

    var dog = {
        getMyDogsNameReq: getMyDogsNameReq,
    };

    return dog;

});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You need to separate out your JavaScript and HTML code as RequireJS wraps your modules in individual closures (sort of namespaces if you will). And access the DOM from within the JavaScript (not the other way around).

Comment: Sorry to be a doof, but I don't fully understand your answer. I have worked on applications where ViewModels were set up and accessible from the UI. I dont want to be using document.getElementById from the js files (as shown in some examples online), as I intend on using Knockout viewmodels in time. Please could you elaborate on how I might access them? Am I missing something that will allow me access into them?

Comment: I'm not familiar with knockout myself but am wondering if maybe this helps http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html

Comment: Thanks @source.rar. I think that will help me on my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@source.rar and [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-large-maintainable-and-testable-knockout-js-applications--net-30996) have set me in the right direction.

Basically, as stated in the comments above, the modules are only being loaded. In order to access them as I am trying to do, they need to be assigned into the DOM in some form.

Changing my main.js file to the following sorts it.

New main.js:

```
define(function (require) {

    var man = require('man');

    window.man = man;
});
```